# Mysql - Increment datetime every n rows in a view

Tags: mysql-5.6

I have two tables and I'd like to increment a datetime field every n rows

```
jobs

| job_id | group_id |     start_date   | limit | delay  |
+--------+----------+------------------+-------+--------+
|    1   |    1     | 2019-10-10 08:00 |   2   |  3600  |
|    2   |    1     | 2019-10-10 14:00 |   0   |    0   |
|    3   |    2     | 2019-10-10 14:00 |   1   |  1800  |


users

| user_id | group_id | user_name  |  row_num |
+---------+----------+------------+----------+
|  xxx    |    1     | Homer      |     1    |
|  xxx    |    1     | Barney     |     2    |
|  xxx    |    1     | Bart       |     3    |
|  xxx    |    1     | Ned        |     4    |
|  xxx    |    1     | Marge      |     5    |
|  xxx    |    1     | Moe        |     6    |
|  xxx    |    1     | Maggie     |     7    |
|  xxx    |    2     | Lisa       |     1    |
|  xxx    |    2     | Otto       |     2    |
|  xxx    |    2     | Marge      |     3    |
```

the result should be this

```
|  job_id  | group_id | user_name | start_date        |
+----------+----------+-----------+-------------------+
|    1     |    1     | Homer     | 2019-10-10 08:00  |
|    1     |    1     | Barney    | 2019-10-10 08:00  |
|    1     |    1     | Bart      | 2019-10-10 09:00  |
|    1     |    1     | Ned       | 2019-10-10 09:00  |
|    1     |    1     | Marge     | 2019-10-10 10:00  |
|    1     |    1     | Moe       | 2019-10-10 10:00  |
|    ...   |   ...    | ...       | ...               |
|    2     |    1     | Homer     | 2019-10-10 14:00  |
|    2     |    1     | Barney    | 2019-10-10 14:00  |
|    2     |    1     | Bart      | 2019-10-10 14:00  |
|    2     |    1     | Ned       | 2019-10-10 14:00  |
|    2     |    1     | Marge     | 2019-10-10 14:00  |
|    2     |    1     | Moe       | 2019-10-10 14:00  |
|    ...   |   ...    | ...       | ...               |
|    3     |    2     | Lisa      | 2019-10-10 14:00  |
|    3     |    2     | Otto      | 2019-10-10 14:30  |
|    3     |    2     | Marge     | 2019-10-10 15:00  |
|    ...   |   ...    | ...       | ...               |
```

To achieve this for now I created a php script that extracts the data, make a loop and inserts them into a table.
I would like to know if you can only do this by using a mysql query and how could I do it.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option:

```
SELECT
    j.job_id,
    j.group_id,
    u.user_name,
    TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR, FLOOR((u.row_num-1) / 2), j.start_date) AS start_date
FROM jobs j
INNER JOIN users u
    ON j.group_id = u.group_id
ORDER BY
    j.job_id,
    j.group_id,
    u.row_num;
```

The logic here is that we add one additional hour to the start date, for every *two* increases in `row_num`, beginning with the second step up in row number (i.e. from 3 onwards).

Comment: I correct FLOOR((u.row_num-1) / 2), u.start_date with FLOOR((u.row_num-1) / 2), j.start_date, and works perfectly with hours. How can I add seconds in the delay field instead of hours? Thank you!

Comment: @PaoloRossi Thanks for pointing that out.  If you want to add seconds to the delay field instead of hours, then use something like `TIMESTAMPADD(SECOND, quantity, j.start_date)`